# How to get missing time to a microtime from another one, formatted (H:i:S) with PHP?

Tags: php, datetime, microtime

i am new to stackOverflow, i was wondering how could i get the missing time date to a microtime(true) starting from another microtime(true), and get it formatted like that (H:i:s).
This is my code:

```
$rewardCountdown = microtime(true) - $this->dailyRewardTime; // daily reward is another microtime(true)
$rewardAvailable = $rewardCountdown >= 60 * 60 * 24; // check if 24h are gone so we can get reward
```

Basically i want to get the $rewardCountdown in this format (H:i:s)
I tried and somehow got something like that but i was getting the time increasing instead of decreasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current `microtime` minus a previous `microtime` would be a positive value, of the number of seconds passed between the two times.

If you want to convert seconds into Hours, Minutes and Seconds, you can simply use `gmdate`.

```
$rewardCountdown = microtime(true) - $this->dailyRewardTime;
$date = gmdate('H:i:s', $rewardCountdown);
```